# Column-major array element address

Tags: math, multidimensional-array

I have an n-dimensional array with column-major order. I need to find the address of any element in this array(in memory).

On the Internet, I found only formulas for 1-,2-,3-,4- dimensional arrays [here](http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AoA/Windows/HTML/Arraysa2.html). However, even with them I can't get the address of an element in a multi-dimensional array.

Does somebody knows formula for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `an` is the coordinate in dimension `n` ans `sn` is the size of dimension `n` then the element (a1,a2,...,an) has the address:

```
a1+s1(a2+s2(a3+s3(a4+...)))
```

For multivariable arrays column-major vs row-major doesn't make much sence, but it should just be to swap a1,s1 with a2,s2 to make it column-major.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, but I can't undrestand what is sn. Can you describe this value a little more? If I have 3-dimensional array, what is s1,s2 and s3?

Comment: s1 is the size of the first dimension. If you put the column first, then it's the number of columns. s2 is then the number of rows, and s3 the number of stacks.